# Pycharm Type Hint Not Using Alias Import ZXY as XYZ

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have the following code and Pycharm type hint isn't using the 'alias' that i'm importing as:

`from stripe.api_resources.list_object import ListObject as StripeListObject`

So this function definition `def my_func_name(subscription: StripeListObject, ...):` should read `my_func_name(subscription: StripeListObject, ...` when looking at the tooltip but instead reads `my_func_name(subscription: ListObject, ...):`

Any ideas on why this is and how can I force pycharm to read the 'alias' when looking at the type hint?

Comment: What do you mean by "looking at the type hint"? Is PyCharm actually type-hinting that argument as `ListObject` instead of `StripeListObject` in the actual function definition, or are you looking at a tooltip or something?

Comment: I'm looking at the tooltip (I edited it) but I think I know what is going on. The alias isn't actually changing the class name and so the type is still `ListObject`. Problem is, is that my function definition is saying the argument is the alias. This is a problem because if the tooltip says it wants a ListObject I would assume I could pass in a list, but in reality the code is looking for a Stripe List Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your import, `ListObject` and `StripeListObject` refer to exactly the same type: they're completely interchangeable. This means that if you have some function that accepts a `StripeListObject`, it would be perfectly valid to pass in a `ListObject` or vice-versa. Note that this is also true at runtime: at runtime, `StripListObject` simply just a variable that refers to the underlying `ListObject` class: the "name" of the variable doesn't change the runtime behavior.

This is why PyCharm is saying that the type is `ListObject` when you hover over it: it's biasing towards showing the original name of the type rather then the alias. This is a good thing! It helps prevent people from accidentally thinking that the two types are different (and reflects what happens at runtime).

I strongly suspect this behavior is not configurable: it would be confusing and arguably wrong if PyCharm behaved in any other way.

If you want PyCharm to treat `ListObject` and `StripeListObject` as two distinct types, you'll either need to (a) create a new class named `StripeListObject` (that perhaps inherits from `ListObject`), or (b) make the `StripListObject` a [NewType](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#newtypes) rather then an alias.

Comment: This is what I thought was happening.